# LNK2019 error for Visual Studio - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I am a beginner and running into the above-said error. The following is the complete code from three files:
`ball.h`:

```
#ifndef BALL_H
#define BALL_H
namespace
{
    inline constexpr double gravity{ 9.81 };
}
    double getInitialHeight(void);
    double calculateHeight(double, int);
    void printHeight(double, int);
    void calculateAndPrintHeight(double, int);
    void solve(void);

#endif
```

`ball.cpp`:

```
#include "ball.h"
#include <iostream>

double getInitialHeight()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the height of the tower in meters ";
    double initialHeight{};
    std::cin >> initialHeight;
    return initialHeight;
}

double calculateHeight(double initialHeight, int secondsPassed)
{
    double distanceFallen{ BALL_H::gravity * secondsPassed * secondsPassed / 2.0 };
    double currentHeight{ initialHeight - distanceFallen };
    return currentHeight;
}

void printHeight(double height, int secondsPassed)
{
    if (height > 0.0)
    {
        std::cout << "At " << secondsPassed << " seconds, the ball is at height\t" << height << " meters.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "At " << secondsPassed << " seconds, the ball is on the ground.\n";
        std::exit(0);
    }


}

void calculateAndPrintHeight(double initialHeight, int secondsPassed)
{
    double height{ calculateHeight(initialHeight, secondsPassed) };
    printHeight(height, secondsPassed);
}

void solve()
{
    const double initialHeight{ getInitialHeight() };
    int secondsPassed{ 0 };
    while (true)
    {
        calculateAndPrintHeight(initialHeight, secondsPassed);
        secondsPassed++;
    }
}
```

`Solution.cpp`(the main project file in the solution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ball.h"

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that this problem is caused because linker cannot find a reference to `solve()`. However, I am not sure how to solve the issue. One easy solution is to simply include `ball.cpp` rather than `ball.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ball.cpp"

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works but I'd like to know how to use headers instead since I am not sure if this a good practice.

**EDIT**:
Here's the error list:

[image]

Comment: I expect `ball.cpp` is not part of your Visual Studio project.

Comment: I made a solution called Solution and then manually added two files, one is the header and the other is the cpp file.

Comment: You have 2 cpp files and 1 header. All 3 must be part of the project.

Comment: `Solution.cpp` got created when I made a new solution. Instead of adding any projects, I manually added these 2 files by `File>New>File`. Does that affect the way to how I can access them?

Comment: What symbol is undefined? Please post the complete error message.

Comment: It seems that there is nothing wrong with your operation. In fact, I used `#include "ball.h"` and it worked fine. So, I suggest that you could post the complete error message. Besideds, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [Header files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=msvc-160) and [#include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Comment: I've added the error list, I think it may be due to the fact that I added `ball.h` and `ball.cpp` manually by adding them via `New>File`. I am not sure how that affects the code. Meanwhile, I'll check out the provided links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add header file, you could right click `Header Files` and select `Add->New Item`.

[image]

When you add .cpp file, you could right click `Source Files` and select `Add->New Item`.

[image]

Then, add the following code in `Source.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ball.h"

int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem! Just wanted to add that by default it goes to `external dependencies` folder if added using `New>File`. I'll accept the answer once the threshold time passes, thanks!